# J2ME Puzzle Game

Tags: java-me, puzzle

I'm Creating a game similar to Gift Quest, Where I have to swap elements, Check for Vertical and Horizontal repeated elements then erase repeated ones (if 3 elements are same in a row or column, remove those and fill with new ones)

```
int [][] Board = new int[5][5];
```

I have an integer array as my board i have defined each gift with a specific integer value for example chocolates = 1, candy = 2 etc

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
     for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
     {
         Board[i][j] = rand.nextInt(5);
     }
}
```

I finished the swap part also, Now I want to check the board if there are same element more than 3 times in a row and column.if it is then make that place in array blank. So i can fill it.

Can someone help me with the checking part ?

Comment: You may want to try http://gamedev.stackexchange.com instead. They have a lot of answers to this particular question (it's called "match three").

Comment: thanks ;) I'll post it there then

Answer (score 0):

```
int counter = 0; 
int currentTile = 0;
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
         for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
         {
              if(Board[i,j] == currentTile)
                 Counter++;
              if(Counter == 3)
                 DoStuff(); //Yay 3 in a row!
              currentTile = Board[i,j];

         }
counter = 0;
    }
```

And do the same thing, but swap the loops for the x axis